# How can I trigger an event when a player interacts with a villager?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What I want to do is have it so when a player right clicks on a certain type of villager, the villager will say some stuff to them, for example "Quick, the monsters are in the dungeon!" and the player can progress the villager's speech by right clicking again. Would this be possible in 1.12.2? If not, I'll use 1.13.

Comment: By using the scoreboard type, it's in the wiki.

Comment: Ahh, thanks! Would the player still open the trading menu? I don't really want that to happen.

Comment: Yes. But you can teleport the villager to y=-65, which should instantly kill it and close the menu. That's a standard click detector. Did you just want that? Then Google can help.

Comment: Ah, I found a way! I made a scoreboard objective, then I simply added comparators and stuff to make the villager say stuff in the chat. I used Offers:{Recipes:[]} alongside /entitydata to make it not have anything to trade. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found a way! For anyone wanting the same stuff, summon a villager in the spot you want, then run:

```
/entitydata @e[type=villager,r=5] {Offers:{Recipes:[]},NoAI:1}
```

then do

```
/scoreboard objectives add talk stat.talkToVillager
```

Then make repeating command blocks with

```
/testfor @a[score_talk_min=1,score_talk=1]
```

with chain command blocks going off them with tellraw commands inside. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: You should use conditional chain command blocks instead. No delay, less lag, less space, more reliable and easier to use.

Comment: Oooh, thanks! I'll edit my answer to include that.